# Asp.Net Core 3-1 - Returning Guid to other Action view at controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, guid

I have two actions
1- action :

```
 public IActionResult ShowFirstSubCategory(Guid category)
    {      

        var firstsubcategory = _admin.ShowFirstCategory(category);
        return View(firstsubcategory);
    }
```

2-action :

```
 public IActionResult EditFirstSubCategory(Category firstsubcategory)
    {
       
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(firstsubcategory);
        }         

        _admin.UpdateMainCategory(firstsubcategory);
        return View("ShowFirstSubCategory", firstsubcategory.ParentId);

    }
```

I want `firstsubcategory.ParentId` send to action view `ShowFirstSubCategory`

And get the amount in the action ...

error :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to show another view that has a different model than that the parameter you passed into it. Instead, you should be using `RedirectToAction` like below :

```
return RedirectToAction("ShowFirstSubCategory", new { category = firstsubcategory.ParentId});
```